Invalid tokens after creating the ABP IO container with OpenIddict
Invalid tokens after after creation
the docker of the ABP IO container with OpenIddict. Data Protection is stored in a non-container, but the token signature changes anyway.
Added the builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential(). It didn't help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
